# Linking errors with Shark in Visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to use shark in Visual Studio 2013. I have downloaded boost from NuGet and I have compiled the binaries of shark using VS itself. While using shark in a program, I am getting the link errors -

`error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl shark::csvStringToData(class shark::LabeledData<class shark::blas::vector<double>,unsigned int> &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,enum shark::LabelPosition,char,char,unsigned int)" (?csvStringToData@shark@@YAXAAV?$LabeledData@V?$vector@N@blas@shark@@I@1@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@W4LabelPosition@1@DDI@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl shark::importCSV<double>(class shark::LabeledData<class shark::blas::vector<double>,unsigned int> &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,enum shark::LabelPosition,char,char,unsigned int)" (??$importCSV@N@shark@@YAXAAV?$LabeledData@V?$vector@N@blas@shark@@I@0@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@W4LabelPosition@0@DDI@Z)   c:\Users\sgondala\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2.obj ConsoleApplication2`

I have included Shark include in include directories. 
I have also included shark build libs in Linker -> General -> Additional Library Dependencies `C:\Users\sgondala\Downloads\Shark-3.0.0\build\lib`

I am new to visual studio so I suspect I am linking something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be an old question, but what helped with similar errors I was getting was going under Linker --> Input --> Additional Dependencies and adding shark_debug.lib.